# How to determine broadcast timestamp and confirmation timestamp for a given transaction id?

Tags: electrum, timestamp, broadcast, blockchain-explorer

Given a transaction ID, how can I get:

1. The timestamp that the transaction was first broadcast
2. The timestamp that the transaction was first confirmed

In this case, I sent the transaction -- so I have access to the wallet that signed & broadcast the transaction. This week bitcoin transaction fees have been absurd ($20 for priority), so I sent it with a very low transaction fee, knowing it may take many hours or days to confirm (still faster & cheaper than a fiat Wire transfer).

Finally, the transaction did confirm, but I'm not sure exactly how many hours it took.

When I right click on the transaction and select `View Transaction` in the Electrum wallet, I see a `Date` field that appears identical to the timestamp visible on public blockchain explorers -- so I'm pretty sure that's the timestamp that the transaction was confirmed (or, rather, the [timestamp in the header of the block](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#Block_Headers) that first included this transaction -- which was [accepted by the network](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/54803/how-do-nodes-agree-on-timestamps) and is [more or less precise](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/12564/can-a-miner-set-the-exact-timestamp-of-a-block)).

But where in electrum (or otherwise) can I see the timestamp that the transaction was first signed/broadcast?